# How to make new file permission created in dir same as exist files - linux

Tags: linux, chmod

when ever i create new file into my dir its get new permission like

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 Nov 27  2013 file.txt
```

while my existing old file looks like

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 149200683 Nov 27 15:46 data.tar.gz
```

how to make any new created file take same permission as data.tar.gz without doing manually  ,

```
my file locate at , /var/data/disk1/
```

Comment: Better asked at http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/managing-default-unix-file-permissions-with-adduser-and-umask/ Please google the problem first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup umask in /etc/bashrc or /etc/profile file for all users.
Edit /etc/profile or ~/.bashrc file and add the following line:

```
umask 022
```

Save it, logout and login again

Comment: its gave me -----w--w- 1 root root 0 Nov 27 17:06 ss

Comment: I'm sorry, the correct umask is 022. 755 is the permission you want to get